# Crossover algorithms for permutation matrices

Tags: matrix, combinations, genetic-algorithm, crossover

I'm developing a genetic algorithm to find the optimal connections between points (minimizing distance).
Let's assume we have two lists of points:

```
sources = {s1, s2, s3}

targets = {t1, t2, t3, t4}
```

I decided to represent the genome as a 2D binary array, where:

- rows represent source points
- columns represent target points
- 1s represent the connection between source and target

This representation implies that each column and each row in the matrix can have at most one 1s.

Now I'm struggling to find a crossover operator which preserves the integrity of the solution.

example:

parent1 :

```
[0][1][0][0]
[0][0][1][0]
[1][0][0][0]
```

parent2 :

```
[0][0][1][0]
[1][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][1]
```

offspring : ???

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your representation and assuming that there are more targets than sources, you could use a row-swapping crossover operator with a built-in repair algorithm.

- Randomly select a row (`i`)
- Swap parents' `i-th` row
- Repair children (if required) moving the conflicting `1` to a free (random or near) column

E.g.

1. Row 0 randomly selected

   ```
                PARENT 1                   PARENT 2
       ROW 0  [0][1][0][0] <-crossover-> [0][0][1][0]
       ROW 1  [0][0][1][0]               [1][0][0][0]
       ROW 2  [1][0][0][0]               [0][0][0][1]
   ```
2. Offspring before repair

   ```
         CHILD 1            CHILD 2
       [0][0][1][0]       [0][1][0][0]
       [0][0][1][0]  and  [1][0][0][0]
       [1][0][0][0]       [0][0][0][1]
   ```
3. `CHILD2` is ok (for a column-swapping operator this doesn't happen); `CHILD1` needs the repair operator

   ```
         CHILD 1
       [0][0][X][0]
       [0][0][X][0]
       [1][0][0][0]
   ```
4. Keep the swapped row (row 0) and change the other conflicting row (row 1). Move the 1 to a free column (column 1 or 3)

   ```
         CHILD 1
       [0][0][1][0]
       [0][1][0][0]
       [1][0][0][0]
   ```
5. Offspring

   ```
         CHILD 1            CHILD 2
       [0][0][1][0]       [0][1][0][0]
       [0][1][0][0]  and  [1][0][0][0]
       [1][0][0][0]       [0][0][0][1]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize BFS to this situation. (if I correctly understand task)

In simple graph traversing task you need to find shortest path from start node to finish node, so you need to store for every node distance from start node and predecessor for this node (from what cell you came). Before BFS iterative algorithm you need to add start node to queue. Take one item in each iteration, check if this node is finish node and add neighbors nodes for this node to queue, etc. So, how we can generalize this algorithm to several start and finish nodes. Very simple.

1. You need to add to queue all start nodes.
2. You need to compare every node that you take from queue with every finish nodes. You can use hashset to O(1) lookup.

Time complexity of this generalization doesn't depend on count of start and finish nodes and the same as simple BFS algorithm: O(V+E)